# LWC Apex response handling. Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I had a LWC component which simply update an record. When logic was in one file it was working fine.

```
btn_newPhoneNumberClick() {
        const fields = {};
        fields.Id = this.recordId;
        fields[LEAD_RTID.fieldApiName] = this.findRecordTypeId('Call');
        fields[LEAD_PHONE.fieldApiName] = this.newPhoneNumber;

        const recordInput = { fields };
        updateRecordWithToast(recordInput);
    }

// Require: import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
    updateRecordWithToast(recordInput) {
        updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Lead updated',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
                // Display fresh data in the form
                return refreshApex(this.lead);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error updating record',
                        message: error.body.message + ' \nStatus: ' + error.statusText,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });
    }
```

Now since I have more components which update records I have extracted "updateRecordWithToast" to separate util class lwc_utils.

Imported to prevous one using:

```
import { updateRecordWithToast} from 'c/lwc_utils';
```

Then for **success update** when there is no error I am getting in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at eval (lwc_utils.js:4)
```

Which basically mean that message: error.body.message is undefined which is true in case of success update.

But I do not understand why error branch is evaluated?

Is there any workaround to keep error message and avoid such error?

It breaks at this point so no toast is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the update, the problem is in

`return refreshApex(this.lead);`

`this.lead` does not exist, also when refresh apex gives an exception, the error does not contain body or message thus `error.body.message` is undefined. And your catch block is called.

use

`return refreshApex(this.recordInput);` and this will solve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately it still break in the same way. Even removing refresh apex line doesn't help.

Comment: Lemme provide my github repo. I have this working peice

Comment: @PawełWoźniak can you try this and see if this works for you?
https://github.com/pranayjswl007/generic_lwc_utils_demo/tree/master/src/lwc/lwc_utils

Comment: I am getting 404. It seems that this repo is not public.

Comment: @PawełWoźniak done

Comment: Code from linked repo is working as expected. Coclusion is that "this" must be replaced by main component reference variable as "this" in helper class is not pointing to caller. Thank you Pranay.