# RefreshApex throwing an exception without message body in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have inline DataTable where user can change the value of certain fields and save. The save functionality is working absolutely fine but after save it's going to exception block.

Here is my JS method I am using for Save functionality :

```
handleSave(event) {
        this.saveDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
        saveEditedRecords({
            editedIWList: this.saveDraftValues
            })
            .then(result => {
                // set @track saveStatus variable to get saveStatus
                console.log('Result ' + result);
                this.saveStatus = result;
                //Display Success Message on Save
                const toastEvent1 = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    variant: 'success',
                    message: 'Records successfully saved',
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent1);

                // Clear all draft values
                this.draftValues = [];

                // Use the value to refresh iwsRefreshedVal().
                **return refreshApex(this.iws);**
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // display server exception in toast msg 
                const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error',
                    variant: 'error',
                    message: error,
                });
                this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
                this.saveStatus = null;
            });
    }
```

There is a similar issue pointed in this URL : [LWC Apex response handling. Cannot read property 'message' of undefined](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265012/lwc-apex-response-handling-cannot-read-property-message-of-undefined). But i am not able to figure our what's wrong in my case.

I have defined @track iws and wired mechanism also:

```
@wire(getIWList, { Year: '$selectedYear',
                   Month: '$selectedMonth',
                   CampaignName : '$selectedOppRecordId',
                   Agency : '$selectedAccountRecordId',
                   Advertiser : '$selectedAdvtRecordId' })
    iwsRefreshedVal(value) {
        // Hold on to the provisioned value so we can refresh it later.
        this.iws = value;
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: did you import refreshApex ?

Comment: Yes, Here is all import I am using I am using:  import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getIWList from '@salesforce/apex/IW_search.getIWList';
import saveEditedRecords from '@salesforce/apex/IW_search.saveEditedRecords';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
//import standard toast event 
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'